# Recreating the background for retouched photographs

Tags: edit-mode, photorealism, 2d

I removed a person from some photographs.
How can I use blender to re-add the background and body parts of other people behind the missing person?

If you guys have any suggestions on how I could do this in blender or whatever other programs I may want to look at instead I would really appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69832/realistic-rendering-of-mesh-together-with-image/69862#69862 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63134/how-do-i-mask-out-certain-areas-of-a-photo