# Masking objects so that they appear behind elements on video

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have a live-action scene which has two objects in. One is a building which replicates the building in the footage. The other is a simple cube which has rigid body physics applied to it.

During the scene, the cube falls behind the building. I need to be able to render out the scene with the cube being blocked out or masked by the building model (like it would look in a completely normal scene). but **not** have the building appear in the final render.

To rephrase. I need to be able to layer one object in front of another. However, make the object in front **NOT** appear in the final render but still have its physical properties there, (so the cube will still bounce off it as a normal passive object)

sorry for my terrible phrasing, any help with this would be really great! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63134/how-do-i-mask-out-certain-areas-of-a-photo and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object . Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48122/how-can-i-make-an-object-invisible-when-i-render-in-cycles

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how to put a mask on 3d space](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941)