# how can i get rid of this black line going through the scene. (the one going through the main character}

Tags: compositing-nodes

[Image (Not embedded because it contains nudity)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXQI7.jpg)

See that black line? I want to get rid of that. It's coming from the background layer. I've tried an *erode* node on the background layer but that doesn't work. I tried adding a ColorRamp to get out the dark spots, but when I add a node to the shadow layer it just seems to add a big white spot to the screen.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use the tools from this site 
to upload images so that they are displayed as part of your question. 
See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Please post an image of the nodes you are using

Comment: Take a look at the following links for ideas on how to mask objects: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63134/how-do-i-mask-out-certain-areas-of-a-photo **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117572/how-to-put-a-mask-into-3d-space/117941#117941

Comment: Or you can create a mask, so that there are sections of the image  that are not affected by the composited image in the foreground: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95228/masking-problems/95236#95236

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/using-mask-as-a-garbage-matte-to-hide-an-object